# Runtime not found (Keeps updateing to 1.8.0_51)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I try to play Minecraft but there I can't play "Recent Release" because of my Runtime not being found but really, it keeps updating to 1.8.0_51 while it is asking for 1.8.0_25. Does anyone know how to fix that?

Full Crash Report:

```
Unable to locate the Java runtime.
Error details: The system cannot find the path specified
Filename on disk: javaw.exe
Path: C:/Program Files(x86)\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\javaw.exe
Exists: false
```

(When I looked, The file after jre-x64 was 1.8.0_51)

Comment: Provide a screenshot

Comment: Please attach a complete crash report.

Comment: You don't have Java installed.  Install Java.

Comment: I do have Java. But it keeps updating to 1.8.0_51 instead of 1.8.0_25 and I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(RESOLVED!) I had to change the File Directory from

C:/Program Files(x86)\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\javaw.exe

to

C:/Program Files(x86)\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_51\bin\javaw.exe